# Why wasn't Seven affected by the subnucleonic radiation in the episode One?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the Voyager episode [One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_%28Star_Trek%3a_Voyager%29) the crew is put into stasis chambers when they attempt to enter a nebula and the entire crew suddenly erupts with painful blistering wounds.

The doctor says that

> even the briefest exposure destroys organic tissue.

Why wasn't Seven affected by the radiation?

Comment: Because she ate her vegetables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Seven of Nine](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Seven_of_Nine) still has nanoprobes and other vestiges of her Borg technology that could not be removed as they were tied to her vital functions and removing them would have killed her.

She is more resistant than other humanoids to injury and many forms of radiation, including chroniton and sub nucleonic radiation.

I'm not sure if it was specifically stated in that episode, but one presumes that whatever left-over nanoprobes in her system would be able to repair damaged tissue before it even became visible, or they are able to redirect or transform the radiation into harmless energy.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that her nanoprobes were able to keep up with repairing whatever damage was done to her organic parts, which (1) was less than her whole body because of her mechanical parts, and (2) said mechanical parts may have helped shield parts (or all) of her organic parts.

Answer (score 2):

Every Borg drone has her personal shield adapting to whatever is damaging the drone, may it be phaser fire or other radiation - I don't know if it's stated somewhere wether Seven has lost this ability due to her implant removal or not, but it might be another explanation why the radiation is not damaging her organics

Comment: I don't think she ever used it after being de-assimilated, so it's probably a fair bet that she can't anymore..

Comment: @Izkata- There was an epsidoe where as Seven tried to return to the Borg, a crewmember (don't recall who) fired at her and her shield deflected it.